# How to Apply IF function to text response and a number response?

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, na

In one column I have their response (Drove alone, bus, bike...). In the next column, I am giving a 0 if they drove alone and a 1 if they took any other mode. The problem is that there are also responses -88 and -99 which I need to be blank. Here is my formula `=IF(REGEXMATCH(..., "Drove alone"), 0,1)`. Is there any function like na.rm = in google sheets?

I have tried surrounding in a IFNA function, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe an IFS function, but it's giving me weird responses.

Comment: To add detail I am doing day by day and then I am going to see total days they took a different mode/ total days traveled (so any response besides 88, -99). So I don't think I can make these responses zero cause it will mess up this future calculation. For example if they had a -88 monday, drive alone tuesday, -88 wednesday, and bike for thursday and friday they would have a score of 66% (2/3). If they are converted to zero then they would have a score of 20%(2/5) which would be innacurate.

Comment: When you tag the question *google-sheets*, you don't need to say you're using Google Sheets in the title or the first sentence of your post. The tag system works very well here, and doesn't need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found that =IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(Q4, "Drove alone"), 0,1),"") works so hopefully helps anyone with a similar problem.